# Threads fighting over global variables in class using OpenMP task

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am currently trying to find out does a clique of size k exist in an undirected graph using OpenMP to make the code run faster.

This is the code which I am trying to paralleize:

```
bool Graf::doesCliqueSizeKExistParallel(int k) {
  if (k > n) return false;
  clique_parallel.resize(k);
  bool foundClique = false;

  #pragma omp parallel
  #pragma omp single
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     if (degree[i] >= k - 1) {
      clique_parallel[0] = i;

      #pragma omp task
      doesCliqueSizeKExistParallelRecursive(i + 1, 1, k, foundClique);
  }
}

return foundClique;
}

void Graf::doesCliqueSizeKExistParallelRecursive(int node, int currentLength, int k, bool & foundClique) {
   for (int j(node); j < n; j++) {
   if (degree[j] >= k - 1) {
     clique_parallel[currentLength - 1] = j;
     bool isClique=true;
     for(int i(0);i<currentLength;i++){
       for(int l(i+1);l<currentLength;l++){
        if(!neighbors[clique_parallel[i]][clique_parallel[l]]){isClique=false; break;}
       }
       if(!isClique) break;
     }
     if (isClique) {
       if (currentLength < k)
      doesCliqueSizeKExistParallelRecursive(j + 1, currentLength + 1, k, foundClique);
     else {
      foundClique= true;
      return;
     }
   }
  }
 }

}
```

The problem here, which I suppose could be the case is that the variables `degree`, `neighbors`, `clique_parallel` are all global and when some thread is trying to write in one of these variables, another one comes and writes in that variable instead of the right thread. The only solution which I tried was to pass, these three variables as a copy to the function so that each thread has its own variable, and it didn't work. I am trying not to use `#pragma omp taskwait` because that would just be the sequential algorithm and there wouldn't be any speed up. Currently I am lost and don't how to fix this issue (if it is an issue) and don't know what else to try or how to avoid sharing these variables between threads.

Here is the class `Graf`:

```
  class Graf {
  int n; // number of nodes
  vector<vector<int>> neighbors; //matrix adjacency
  vector<int> degree; //number of nodes each node is adjacent to
  vector<int> clique_parallel;
  bool directGraph;
  void doesCliqueSizeKExistParallelRecursive(int node, int currentLength, int k, bool & foundClique);
  public:
  Graf(int n, bool directGraph = false);
  void addEdge(int i, int j);
  void printGraf();
  bool doesCliqueSizeKExistParallel(int k);

};
```

So my question is, here in this code the problem that the threads are fighting over the global variables, or could it be somethin else? Any help is useful, and if you have any question regarding the code, I'll answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation that `omp task wait` turns this into the sequential algorithm is sort of correct. It's in fact worse: it turns your Depth-First search algorithm into effectively a Breadth-First, which would traverse the whole space.

Ok. First of all use `task group`, which has an implicit task wait at the end of a for loop that generates tasks.

Next, let your tasks return either false, or the values of a clique found.

Now for the big trick: once one task has found a solution, call `omp cancel task group`, which makes you leave the for loop and you can keep the values you found! This cancel will kill all other tasks (and their recursively spawned tasks) at that level. And now the magic of recursion kicks in and all groups get cancelled higher up the tree.

I once figured this out for another recursive search problem, but I'm sure you can translate it to your problem: [https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-examples.html#Treetraversal](https://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/%7Eeijkhout/pcse/html/omp-examples.html#Treetraversal)

Comment: I listened to your advice, and the algorithm now works perfectly but the only problem now is that even if I add `#pragma omp cancel taskgroup` it doesn't cancel the for loop. Here is the new code: https://pastebin.com/Hie3CRq1

Comment: Did you catch the statement that you need to set an environment variable `OMP_CANCELLATION=true`? I have no idea why that's false by default.

Comment: Yes i setted `OMP_CANCELLATION=true`, here is the proof  https://ibb.co/C79xDV7

Comment: Why do you think it's not cancelling?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Does it support task cancellation?

Comment: This is how I tested it, here is the code where I added the cout of foundClique, https://pastebin.com/J1HS98Py and this is the output of a random graph of size 20, https://ibb.co/1mTc6mB when he finds one clique I presume that it still enters tasks, and I am using the TDM GCC compiler